# Performance Issues in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

We are working on DB conversion from SQL Server to Aurora PostgreSQL.
For some of the functions in a database, we are seeing very high execution times in PG (30+ seconds) compared to SQL Server(0.5-2 seconds).

We have already set the database parameters to values required for optimal performance.

Many of these functions reference tables from another database using views on foreign tables.

Client expectation is the performance of the functions should be at least, if not better, than what we currently have in SQL server.

What are ways to improve the performance in PG?

Below are the respective config details:

```
SQL server config: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) – 11.0.7001.0 (X64). RAM: 16GB. Inter Xeon
Aurora RDS config: 4 vCPU, 30.5 GB RAM.
```

Sample Code:

Code Example:// this one taking less then one seconds.

```
insert into temptable(
                column1 ,column2,column3 ,
                column4 ,column5, column6 ,
                column7                                                             
        )
    SELECT  --DISTINCT
        t.col AS column1, d.column1,null as column3 ,
                null as column4 ,null as column5,null as column6 ,
                null as column7 
    FROM 
        view1 AS d
        INNER JOIN table2 AS t
            ON t.column2= d.column1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS i
            ON i.col1 = t.col AND i.col = t.col2 AND i.col = var1 AND i.svc_type = var2
            AND i.col2= var3 AND i.col1 = var4
    WHERE 
        (i.col3 = 'XXX' OR d.col3 = 'XX') 
        AND i.col4 IN (var5, var6) 
        ;
// This update query only taking 27 seconds and result 39 rows      
update temptable set 
        column3=function1(column2, v1, v2, v3), -- this is single execution it took 412ms
        column4=function2(column2, v3),-- this is single execution it took 350ms
        column5=function3(column2, v3),
        column6=function4(column2),
        column7=function5(column2);
// this one taking less then one seconds.
OPEN rs1 FOR
    select  column1 ,column2,column3 ,
                column4 ,column5, column6 ,
                column7 from temptable;
    RETURN NEXT rs1;
```

Comment: `We have already set the database parameters to values required for optimal performance` - I disagree.

Comment: Learn to analyze queries. Experience with Postgres has taught me that one misplaced join, unnecessary CTE, or non-indexed where statement can turn a 20ms query into a 2 minute query. Put `explain analyze` in front of your queries and learn how to read the output.

Comment: Please explain in detail what tuning have you already done, and what are the challenging functions doing. This would help us understand your situation better to help you out.

Comment: In order to help, we need concrete queries and their execution plan (`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`) at least (if possible, activate I/O timing inclusion using `SET track_io_timing TO on;` before the `EXPLAIN`. A good tool to visualize the output is at https://explain.depesz.com/ . In order to determine the slowest queries, please activate the `pg_stat_statements` extension and come back with the slowest query first.

Comment: Do you have statistics for the foreign tables?  Autovacuum does NOT gather statistics for foreign tables, so you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Your update uses 5 different functions. Each one is called as many times as the table has rows, so 39 times. So if the first two function take 400ms calling + 320ms that is done  39 times and that's pretty much the time you claim the update statement takes. So your bottleneck are the functions, not the UPDATE. But without seeing what those functions do, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Here all are calling foreign table. If any possible to improve performance in Foreign tables.

Comment: I'm probably too late since this question is more than 1 year old but I really think you should try to use plain Postgres with RDS rather than Aurora for Postgres.